Confusing definitions of EMF
I was studying about EMF (electromotive force) recently but had trouble connecting the two definitions of the topic. Here are the two definitions of EMF listed in my book (The book I've referred is: New Simplified Physics (Vol.1) by S.L. Arora):

"The electromotive force of a source may be defined as the work done by the source in taking a unit positive charge from lower to higher potential."

"The emf of a source may be defined as the energy supplied by the source in taking a unit positive charge once round the complete circuit."


According to my understanding, the two definitions seem rather conflicting as definition (1) suggests that emf is the work done in moving the charge from lower potential to higher potential (i.e. inside the cell itself) but definition (2) suggests that emf is the energy supplied (which will be equal to the work done) in moving the cell across the entire circuit (instead of just inside the cell).
I assume that this misinterpretation by me is due to an error at the conceptual level of the topic. It would be helpful if anyone could clear it (and/or) provide a source to study it.

I think the first definition might refer to the EMF on open circuit, and the second might refer to the case of closed circuit. It can't be confirmed unless you cite the book that you use.

The book which I've referred is : New Simplified Physics (Vol.1) by S.L. Arora.  And yes, I see in the book that the second definition is written for a closed circuit although there's no clear explanation given on why the case is.

The formal definition of the electromotive force can be written as follows.
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{E} = \sum_{i} \int_{L} \mathbf {f_i} \cdot d\mathbf{l}
\end{equation}
Where $\mathbf{f_i}$ is the force acting on charge carriers by the i-th source, and $\mathbf{L}$ is the path over which integral is carried on. From the definition, it doesn't matter if L is open or closed circuit. In case of open circuit it becomes.
\begin{equation}
\int_{L} \mathbf {f} \cdot d\mathbf{l} =\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf L(t)}{\partial t} dt 
\end{equation}
Where $t$ is parameter for the integration on a curve, and $b$ and $a$ are the values of $t$ on the edges of the curve.

So in the case of an open circuit we just integrate from points A to B i.e. the terminals of the battery and in the case of a closed circuit we integrate along the entire loop? I'm unable to build intuition regarding this, could you give some reasoning for why this is the case? (I'm extremely sorry if this doubt is a bit dumb, it is just that the concept is new to me and building logic is a bit hard.)

No need to apologize for trying to understand better. In the case of the open circuit, the A and B points aren't necessarily the terminals of the battery. They can be the open ends for some open circuit. If you connect A and B in case of the open circuit, the resulting circuit will be a closed one. In this case we still integrate from A to B, but since they are the same point, we integrate over the entire loop.

I read about the formal definition of electromotive force on Wikipedia and therein they have considered A and B as the terminals of the battery in the case of an open circuit instead of any arbitrary open ends?

Also, what is the "type of force" acting on the charge carriers (is it Electrostatic or Non-Electrostatic)? How is it that the source (e.g. A cell) applies force on all the charge carriers in the entire circuit? And in my comment above, if A and B are open ends instead of terminals of battery then the distance of the path increases which must affect our answer?
